# Change css class style with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Given the below css style, how can I reset the background-color with javascript? Not just for the currently highlighted button, but for all those highlighted in the future?

```
#bottom_buttons > div.bottom_button.highlighted {
    background-color: #343434;
}
```

For instance: 
`$("div.bottom_button.highlighted").css("background-color", "#e67300");`
this works, but is overwritten as soon as the page changes. IE loses focus or updates.

Similarly 
`document.getElementById("bottom_button_" + button).style.backgroundColor = "#e67300";`
works to change the numbered button on click, but also doesn't last.

Comment: What do you mean by "as soon as the page changes"?

Comment: Beside doing frontend action, you need to work on backend to record the what you have done, e.g. by jquery ajax or cookie etc., otherwise server will return same response when "page changes"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be difficult to have persistent changes in CSS from page to page with a refresh. That being said you can do it with local storage.

**Here's how you do it :**

```js
function overwriteStyles(styles) {

  var styleOverwrites = document.getElementById('style-overwrites');

  if (styleOverwrites === null) {
    styleOverwrites = document.createElement('style');
    styleOverwrites.id = 'style-overwrites';
    document.head.appendChild(styleOverwrites);
  }

  styleOverwrites.innerHTML = styles;
  
// Save styles to local storage
  localStorage.setItem('overridden-styles', styles);
}



// Here styles are grabbed from local storage and loaded for persistence

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 

  var styles = localStorage.getItem('overriden-styles');
  
  if(styles != null)
  {
   overwriteStyles(styles);
  }
  
});

// Example of overwriting styles

overwriteStyles(`
  #bottom_buttons > div.bottom_button.highlighted {
    background-color: #e67300;
  }
`);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much. Now to see if there are any other styles I want to replace.